# how to find the average number of rolls it takes to complete a snakes and ladders game?

Tags: python

write code to simulate the game for one player and calculate the number of dice throws required to finish a game. The user should be allowed to specify the number of games simulated and the code should calculate the average number of dice throws per game.

```
#Snakes and Ladders simulation

import random #importing the random function to be able to use it later on

counterposition = 0 #setting counterposition and diceroll to 0
currentDiceroll = 0

def diceroll (): #when user rolls the 1-6 dice this does it randomly
    return random.randint (1,6)
userInput = int(input("How many games would you like to play snakes and ladders?"))

for i in range (userInput):
    currentDiceroll = diceroll()
    print("The currentDiceroll is", currentDiceroll)

    if counterposition == 1:                    #all the if statements show what happens if the one player lands on a snake or a ladder
        counterposition = counterposition + 37
    if counterposition == 4:
        counterposition = counterposition + 10
    if counterposition == 9:
        counterposition = counterposition + 22
    if counterposition == 21:
        counterposition = counterposition + 21
    if counterposition == 28:
        counterposition = counterposition + 56
    if counterposition == 51:
        counterposition = counterposition + 16
    if counterposition == 72:
        counterposition = counterposition + 19
    if counterposition == 80:
        counterposition = counterposition + 19
    if counterposition == 17:
        counterposition = counterposition - 10
    if counterposition == 54:
        counterposition = counterposition - 20
    if counterposition == 63:
        counterposition = counterposition - 4
    if counterposition == 64:
        counterposition = counterposition - 4
    if counterposition == 87:
        counterposition = counterposition - 51
    if counterposition == 92:
        counterposition = counterposition - 19
    if counterposition == 95:
        counterposition = counterposition - 20
    if counterposition == 98:
        counterposition = counterposition - 19
    if counterposition >= 100:
        print ("Congratulations end of game")

    counterposition = counterposition + currentDiceroll
    print("the counter position is", counterposition)
```

Comment: run many times, and remeber number of rolls for every game, after last games calculate average.

Comment: i mean to make python calculate the average as i want to do 10,000 games

Comment: inside `for` loop you need `while` loop which you leave when `counterposition >= 100`. And inside `while` you count how may times you roll.

Comment: `while` will make one, full game. And `for` will repeate this game 10,000 times.

Comment: what would i change my code to to make this work then

Comment: see @A.Sokol answer - he uses `while` inside `for` but not directly.

Answer (score 4):

The code that you have written only rolls the dice one time. You need to keep rolling until you have won the game. It might be best to create a function that plays the game one time and returns the number of dice rolls needed.

```
def playGame():
    counterPosition = 0
    numberOfRolls = 0
    while (counterPosition < 100):
        numberOfRolls += 1
        currentDiceroll = diceroll()
        print("The currentDiceroll is", currentDiceroll)
        counterPosition += currentDiceroll
        # your if statements go here
    return numberOfRolls
```

Then you can call this function however many times you want.

```
totalDiceRolls = 0
for i in range(userInput):
    totalDiceRolls += playGame()
avgRolls = totalDiceRolls / userInput
```

Comment: I had to add my comment as an answer because it was too long :-)

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't what you explicitly asked about, but your code is a bit repetitious with all of those `if` statements. One thing you can do is to conceptualize a move as consisting of moving by the amount given by the die roll, followed by a "bump" which is 0 for most squares, a positive number for squares where a ladder starts, and a negative number for squares at the top of a snake. A dictionary is the natural data structure for the bumps, with only the negative and positive bumps stored explicitly. The dictionary method `get()` can be used to either return the bump if the final square is a key in the dictionary or return the default `0` if it isn't. Then a single game simulation could simply be:

```
bump = {1:37, 4:10, 9:22, 21:21, 28:56, 51:16, 72:19, 80:19, 17:-10, 54: -20, 63: -4, 64: -4, 87: -51, 92: -19, 95:-20, 98: -19}

def simulateGame():
    pos = 0
    count = 0
    while pos < 100:
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        pos += roll + bump.get(pos,0)
        count += 1
    return count
```

And the expected number of rolls can be estimated by:

```
def expectedRolls(trials = 10000):
    return sum(simulateGame() for i in range(trials))/trials
```

Some of the above might involve things that you haven't seen yet, but when you find yourself writing long sections of almost identical code you should if at all possible streamline it. Repetitious code is not pythonic.

If you haven't studied dictionaries yet but have studied lists, you could make `bump` an array with 101 items initialized like: `bump = [0]*101` (101 zeros) and then have a series of assignment like `bump[1] = 37`, `bump[4] = 10`, etc. And then replace the line:

```
pos += roll + bump.get(pos,0)
```

by the even simpler line:

```
pos += roll + bump[0]
```

which in effect says "add to the current position the roll plus any resulting bump"

The code

```
def expectedRolls(trials = 10000):
    return sum(simulateGame() for i in range(trials))/trials
```

uses a generator expression inside of the sum function. If you aren't familiar with those yet, you can add them in an explicit loop as in the excellent answer of A. Sokol

Comment: can you dumb it down a bit please?

Comment: @Ben  I added some more explanation, but didn't attempt to explain it all. If the above code still doesn't make sense, see it again in a couple of months (or whenever), after you have learned about dictionaries and comprehensions.